# Separating components in a component-based UI

Tags: website-design, bootstrap, component

I've got a page for a Team Overview that currently shows everything that is possible to do with a team. [image: team home]

I think that the design for this is loud and hard to read at first glance. The current scaffolding is 2 bootstrap columns with 2 rows in each column.

What's the best way to separate these 4 'components' of this page? Using a background and border on each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, background and border on each component will definitely make it more visible, like on [this dashboard sample](http://demos.shieldui.com/sample-apps/bootstrap-responsive-dashboard).

You can also check [this blog post](http://www.shieldui.com/blogs/designing-informational-dashboards) for some guidelines on how to design dashboard user interfaces, which is the best candidate of what I am seeing from your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Components looks crowded but it needs good visual design. Some breathing space and seperator would solve the problem.